# Что производительнее: HashMap.values() или HashMap.entrySet()?

Tags: java, производительность, java-hashmap

Каким способом можно пройтись по всем значениям производительнее (ключи не нужны)  в `HashMap`?

```
for (Map.Entry<Key, Value> entry : map.entrySet()){
    Value value = entry.getValue();
    ...
}
```

или:

```
for (Value value : map.values()){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Наткнулся на [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/278313/), которая, возможно, будет Вам интересна. Это ещё не ответ на вопрос, но уже достаточно близко.